# Supply and demand equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a hard time factoring this equation to find the equilibrium quantity and price.

> $11p+3x-66 =0$ and $2p^2+p-x=10$

I have gotten this far.

$11p+3x-66=2p^2+p-x-10$

$11p+3x-66-2p^2-p+x+10=0$

$-2p^2-10p-56+4x=0$

$-2p^2-10p-56=-4x$

Then I get stuck here.  I don't know if I'm doing this right.

Comment: You have a sign error: $$ 11p+3x-66-2p^2-p+x+10=0 \Rightarrow -2p^2\color{blue}{+}10p-56+4x=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the second equation by $3$ and add to the first; this will eliminate $x$. So, $$11p+3x-66+3(2p^2+p-x-10)=6 p^2+14 p-96=0$$ The solutions of the quadratic are $p=-\frac{16}{3}$ and $p=3$ the last being the only valid solution.

Now, use any of the equations, replace $p$ by $3$ and get the value of $x$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

1. $11p+3x-66=0$
2. $2p^{2}+p-x=10$

Write down the first equation in terms of $x$ to get $x=\frac{66-11p}{3}$.

Substitute the value of $x$ in equation $2$ to obtain:

$2p^{2}+p-x=10\Rightarrow 2p^{2}+p - \left ( \frac{66-11p}{3} \right )=10 \Rightarrow \frac{6p^{2}+3p-66+11p}{3}=10 \Rightarrow 6p^{2}+14p-96=0 \Rightarrow 3p^{2}+7p-48=0$.

Then you use the **Quadratic formula**: $x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2- 4ab} }{2a}$ to solve for $p$. After finding out your $p$'s you find out your $x$'s by substituting the values of $p$ back in equation $1$ or $2$. Avoid negative price or quantity since it is not realistic.

Remember equilibrium price and quantity occur when demand = supply.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful

Comment: You're welcome. You can also upvote my answer if it's helpful.